# selecting range of values based upon first few characters in spss?

Tags: spss

I know that through

```
select cases if char.substr(variable_name,1,3)="I22".
```

I can select values based on the first # of characters but this is not exactly my question. I need to select RANGE OF values that start with few characters, here is an example of what I want:

if I have the following cases:

I22A33
I22B33
I22C33
I22D33

So I want to select I22B33 and I22C33 out of the above 4 values, so it's like a range of cases between b and c.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: My answer below assumes in this range of values that you want to select, all the values will start with either "I22B" or "I22C". If this is not the right definition of the range of values, please edit your post and elaborate more on your explanation (better add some more data points to your example too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to flag any cases that meet your criteria is using `INDEX` and a series of `OR` conditions.  Not particularly modular, but if you just have a couple of conditions you're searching for it could get you on your way.

Edit: These searches are case-insensitive (due to `UPCASE`) and search for matches at the start of the string.  To search for matches anywhere within the string set the condition to `> 0` (instead of `= 1`).

```
COMPUTE f_I22 = (INDEX(UPCASE(var_name),'I22B33') = 1)
  OR (INDEX(UPCASE(var_name),'I22C33') = 1) .
EXE .
```

Comment: Using `char.index(...) > 0` might end up selecting cases where the string appears in the middle of the text and not at it's beginnig. So better `char.index(...) = 1`.

Comment: That's a good point - OP does say matches are at start of string. edited.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming in this range of values that you want to select, all the values will start with either "I22B" or "I22C", you can simply use:

```
select cases if char.substr(variable_name,1,4)="I22B" or 
                char.substr(variable_name,1,4)="I22C".
```